# JMeter RegEx: How do I extract a specific value I want

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract a specific value I want regardless of match number. I am using -1 for Match No to get all the values.  For example, I may get the following values (3 matches):

- A
- B
- C

I  may get 2 results (just A & B) sometime or 4 results (A,B,C,D) sometime but I always want to select and use a **particular value (say B) irrespective of number of matches returned**.

Comment: Looks like you want to check if the value `B` exists in the result? You may write a regular expression to check if the value exists and check the value is not the `default` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) you will see the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) generated by the Regular Expression Extractor in the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

[image]

so 2nd match can always be referred as `${result_2}` (replace `result` with the actual variable name from your Regular Expression Extractor)

Comment: Sorry, Dmitri. I am aware of that but my question is: I get only 1 result sometime or 4 results sometime so irrespective of the position, I would like to choose the one with the specific value say B and use it further in a IF controller

Comment: In other words, B may appear in second position sometimes or in third position sometime

Comment: If you don't need the other values, just `B` you need to change your regular expression to return just `B` (or use other more suitable Post-Processor like [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) or [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) or whatever, hard to say without seeing your full response )